# How to check if an infinite line intersects a rectangular prism in 3d space?

Tags: math, geometry, linear-algebra

If I have a line segment defined by two points p1, p2, and then a rectangular prism defined by (x,y,z) (lowest corner point) with length/width/height (l, w, h), how can I check if the line will intersect the prism? And also get the point of intersection if there is one?

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Seems that your prism is axis-aligned box (rectangular parallelepiped).

So use any algorithm intended for [line clipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_clipping) - for example, 3D-version of Liang-Barsky algorithm

In short - make parametric equation for line segment

```
X = X1 + t * (X2 - X1)
Y = Y1 + t * (Y2 - Y1)
Z = Z1 + t * (Z2 - Z1)
```

find parameters t for intersection with faces: substitute `X = x`  or `X = x + l` in equation, find t, check if point with this t lies inside face rectangle