# How to check if a line lies between a prism

Tags: java, 3d, geometry, raytracing

If I have 2 points in 3d space how can I determine if a rectangular prism lies between those 2 points? Also the only information I have about the the rectangular prism is its min and max x, y, and z value. I know I could iterate down the line between those 2 points checking to see if that point is within the rectangular prism but that seems very resource heavy. What I really need is a way to check if a line segment intersects the prism but I am not sure how to do that any ideas?

I found these two resources that seem similar to my question
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2134505/how-to-check-if-an-infinite-line-intersects-a-rectangular-prism-in-3d-space

[How to check if an infinite line intersects a rectangular prism in 3d space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42105593/how-to-check-if-an-infinite-line-intersects-a-rectangular-prism-in-3d-space)

Looking at that bottom link it just simply says to find parameters t that intersects the rectangular prism which is obvious but the problem is I dont know how to do that any thoughts?

Comment: Have you read about line clipping? Do you understand what is parametric representation of line?

Comment: Yes but I still dont know how to do it with code.

Comment: Is your prism axis-aligned box?

Comment: Yes I assume so there is a min and max for all 3 values (x, y, and z).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let line segment is defined by two points `(X1, Y1)` and `(X2, Y2)`.
Let box is defined by ranges `xmin..xmax`, `ymin..ymax`, `zmin..zmax`.

We can write parametric eqiation for line segment, where `t` is in range 0..1:

```
X = X1 + t * (X2 - X1)
Y = Y1 + t * (Y2 - Y1)
Z = Z1 + t * (Z2 - Z1)
```

Box has 6 facets. Let the first one is at `xmin`. We can substitute `xmin` in the first equation and find parameter `t` where line intersects this facet.

```
xmin = X1 + t1 * (X2 - X1)
t1 = (xmin - X1) / (X2 - X1)
```

Now check that `t1` is in range `0..1`. If yes, substitute this `t1` value in the second and third equations

```
Y = Y1 + t1 * (Y2 - Y1)
Z = Z1 + t1 * (Z2 - Z1)
```

and check that resulting Y and Z lie in ranges `ymin..ymax` and `zmin..zmax` respectively.
If yes - **line segment does intersect the box**

If no, repeat for other faces `xmax`, `ymin` and so on.

P.S. Also you can consider special case when line segment is fully inside the box (just check if X1,Y1,Z1 is in box range)

P.P.S. When line is parallel to some coordinate plane, don't check intersections with corresponding  faces (for example, if `X2-X1==0`, you cannot divide by zero, but you just don't need check `xmin` and `xmax` faces)

Quick-made Python-like pseudocode for reference:

```
def DoesSegmentIntersectBox(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,xmin,xmax,yin,ymax,zmin,zmax):
    if zmin<=z1<=zmax and ymin<=y1<=ymax and xmin<=x1<=xmax:
        return True  #end inside the box

    if (x2-x1):
        t = (xmin-x1) / (x2-x1)
        if 0<=t<=1:    #line intersects plane in segment range
            y = y1+t*(y2-y1)
            if ymin<=y<=ymax:    #segment intersects face in y range
                z = z1+t*(z2-z1)
                if zmin<=z<=zmax:   #segment intersects face in z range
                    return True     #segment does intersect face xmin
        t = (xmax-x1) / (x2-x1)
            #same 6 lines

    if (y2-y1):
        t = (ymin-y1) / (y2-y1)
        if 0<=t<=1:
            x = x1+t*(x2-x1)
            if xmin<=x<=xmax:
                z = z1+t*(z2-z1)
                if zmin<=z<=zmax:
                    return True
        t = (ymax-y1) / (y2-y1)
            #same 6 lines

    if (z2-z1):
        t = (zmin-z1) / (z2-z1)
        if 0<=t<=1:
            x = x1+t*(x2-x1)
            if xmin<=x<=xmax:
                y = y1+t*(y2-y1)
                if ymin<=y<=ymax:
                    return True
        t = (zmax-z1) / (z2-z1)
            #same 6 lines

    return False
```

Comment: How does your second snippet of code work because you have circular references. xMin had t1 and t1 references xmin or are you saying I need to solve them as a system of equations?

Comment: No circular reference, just one formula    `t1 = (xmin - X1) / (X2 - X1)` derived from the first line

Comment: Alright and then I do this for the other 5? So if one of the 6 intersects then the line has collided with the box?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If one intersects, you can stop.

Comment: Alright ill try it out and if it I dont have any issues ill accept your answer. Also are the max done the same as the min like t1 = (xmax - X1) / (X2 - X1)

Comment: Yes, formula for max is the same. I added a pair od special cases.

Comment: Alright just as some clarification when I found xT1 (aka t1 that uses xmin) do I first check if the number is between 0 and 1 and then plugin that value for all 3 equations and then take that new x, y, and z and check if its within the rectangular prisms bounding box? That means I would have to do 18 calculations since I would need to test all 6 min and max variants by plugging them into the 3 equations separately and verifying each time if those new points fall between my original min and max values.

Comment: I added pseudocode (not checked thoroughly)

Comment: Alright that makes sense thank you!

Answer (score 1):

project your line points and prism edges onto 2D plane that is perpendicular to your line.
[image]
On the 2D plane, the two points of line will be just one point and prism edges is just a bunch of connected vertices forming a closed region. check if the one point is within the closed region, this will be easy to do for 2D.

If your point is within then the line intersects the prism in 3D, if not then no.

now there is a case where it is a line segment where the two ends don't touch the prism. In this case you just check point to prism surface distance, there is a equation for that.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of this because I am not following how I would actually do this.

Comment: @UnSure yes, I added a illustration

Comment: I am not sure how I am suppose to do any of this within java. I mean I have the min and max values of the box already however I dont see how you explanation helps me solve this problem. I understand how to solve this problem by logically looking at it but I dont know how to actually do it with software so that I can solve it for any point location. If we look at that second link we can see the parametric equations so how do I go from that to being able to get t and check for intersections?

My big question is how not why.

Comment: @UnSure would you like I offer a c++ solution? Java is beyond me.

Comment: Yea a c++ will work I dont really know it but I bet I could follow the logic since its similar

Comment: @UnSure ok, no problem, I will add code a bit later, right now working so will take some time.

Comment: any update on that c++ code?